# Как привязать команду к ListViewItem? MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, wpf-commands

разработчики:)

Стоит задача привязать команду к ListViewItem для того, чтобы метод команды выполнялся коректно...

Сейчас у меня следующий код:
**XAML**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myBaseVM}, Path=GameList}"
                  SelectedIndex="{Binding Source={StaticResource myBaseVM}, Path=Indexer, 
            Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                  VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="270"
                                Background="FloralWhite">
                        <Grid Background="DarkSalmon">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Height="50" Width="50" Margin="5"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding GameName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <Button Height="25"
                                    Command="{Binding StartGameCommands, Source={StaticResource myBaseVM}}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Он прекрасно работает при заполнении коллекции, но мне важно определять индекс выделенного элемента в списке.

Для того, чтобы коректно выполнился следующий код:
**VM**

```
public void StartGame()
    {
        var a = Indexer;
        var b = InfoGame.ElementAt(a).FullPath;
        Process.Start(b);
    }
```

Данный метод, по индексу, выполняет поиск пути к игре в коллекции, чтобы её запустить, когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку.

Класс реализующий команду:

```
  **public class StartGameCommands : ICommand
    {
    public BaseVM baseVM { get; set; }

    public StartGameCommands(BaseVM baseVM)
    {
        this.baseVM = baseVM;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        baseVM.StartGame();
    }
}**
```

Но проблема в том, что при нажатии на кнопку индекс еще не успевает определиться, поэтому он всегда равен нулю. А если сначала щелкнуть просто на элемент рядом с кнопкой, то он определиться коректно.
[image: Так выглядит ListView при заполнении данными]

Возможно ли как-то привязать команду непосредственно к ListViewItem ?
Или как то переписать XAML код, чтобы индекс определялся сразу, как только пользователь нажмёт на кнопку ?

Comment: Передавайте текущий элемент как параметр в команду и используйте его `CommandParameter="{Binding}"`, свойство, отслеживающее выбранный элемент вам при этом не нужно. Так как вы не показали реализацию команды, правильный ответ на ваш вопрос дать невозможно, можно только гадать. И не используйте `SelectedIndex`, используйте `SelectedItem`, оно удобнее, не придется каждый раз искать этот элемент в списке по индексу.

Comment: @aepot , спасибо за ответ

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужна реализация команды, которая позволит передать параметр.

Например эта.

```cs
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    public void Execute(object parameter) => _execute(parameter);
}
```

Далее во вьюмодели объявите свойство

```cs
public ICommand StartGameCommand { get; }
```

И присвойте значение в конструкторе. Так как я не знаю, какого типа коллекция `InfoGame`, пусть будет это `ObservableCollection<GameInfo>`. Тогда код будет такой.

```
public BaseVM()
{
    StartGameCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        var info = (GameInfo)parameter;
        Process.Start(info.FullPath);
    }, parameter => parameter is GameInfo); // CanExecute задизаблит кнопку, если параметр не нужного типа, например если он null
}
```

В разметке это будет выглядеть так

```xml
<Button Height="25"
        Command="{Binding StartGameCommand, Source={StaticResource myBaseVM}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```

Кстати, такая реализация команды позволяет использовать один универсальный `RelayCommand` для всех команд, передавая исполняемую часть команды как делегат в виде лямбда-выражения. Очень удобно. Так же поддерживает `CanExecute`. Он необязателен, и его можно выбросить при создании команды, но я бы на вашем месте изучил полезность этой функции команды.

Comment: Спасибо большое, Ваш ответ помог мне :) Благодаря Вам моя программа близка к завершению :)